# Android - change font of navigation drawer/text

Tags: android, xml, fonts

I am implementing a navigation drawer into my app and I want to change the font. Below is my oncreate method where I change the font of the navigation drawer the problem is when the app runs it crashes instantly and I cant figure out what is wrong

Code:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navdrawer);

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    Home fragment = new Home();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.llhome, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "robotomed.ttf");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvmenu);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);

    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    // Set the list's click listener

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
    mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
    R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
    R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
    ) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle("Home");
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle("StayHealthy");
        }
    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);



}
```

here is my logcat

```
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.OptimusApps.stayhealthy/com.OptimusApps.stayhealthy.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2079)
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042):    at com.OptimusApps.stayhealthy.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-22 21:44:21.562: E/AndroidRuntime(32042):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The logcat has found a NullPointerException, so it's likely the typeface is not loaded correctly. Can you verify that your `robotomed.tff` is indeed in the `/assets` of your project?

Check [here](http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/17/using-assets-in-android/) for more information about assets.

Answer (score 0):

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(),
            "fonts/robotomed.ttf");
```

//getBaseContext() is same thing as MainActivity.this

I suggest creating the assets folder and adding a fonts directory inside of it. You call the assets folder from your activity and your font from your font directory. Also, depending on the structure of your xml files, you might not be able to use findViewById(). The reason is that your TextView might be a part of a ListAdapter (think list item). With that being said, you would not be able to call that Id if it applies to a ListAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `app:itemTextAppearance="@font/poppins"` to `NavigationView`, as below:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemTextAppearance="@font/poppins"
    ...
```